Is there anything about this itinerary from Eva air that looks like it could be a fake?
Is there anything about this itinerary from Eva air from June/July 2023 that looks like it could be a fake?


If you need to ask then it is probably fake. Why are you asking?

Did you buy the ticket yourself or did you send money to the passenger so they could buy it? Did you get an original confirmation from the airline or did the passenger send it to you?If the latter, it could be a genuine itinerary that’s been edited eg with a name change.

I'm asking because this individual lied about many many things in relation to this specific trip, and thbe itinerary just doesn't have an official appearance to me.

the passenger sent this to me, i didn't purchase the ticket myself

There's nothing obviously wrong in that itinerary, but it's dead easy to produce a fake one. If it's fake at least they made an effort to produce something without the myriad of errors usually found in fakes, but that doesn't mean much either way. Maybe slightly weird that it's all Y one way and all S the other, or that there's a confirmed seat only on a single flight, but there could be many valid reasons for either.

If you google image search "eva air itinerary" this is the only image that shows up that has this format, so that's one thing to consider. It could be from a travel agent's own system or some other booking system perhaps, but it's a highly unusual format.

@ave I'm pretty sure I've had itineraries in similar formats, though probably a long time ago. Nowadays most airlines like to add all sorts of colours and different fonts and styles, but good old teletype format straight out of the GDS works. A very similar format: https://www.scribd.com/document/723726514/Itinerary-Qezag3-Ouedraogo-Wendab-Meliane-Aida-Mrs-294692961

@jcaron yeah, I'm familiar with the format, but it's definitely less common in mid-2023.

Please add additional information to the question (it's called "edit"), not in additional comments!

The itinerary looks legitimate, those are actual EVA flights with sensible connecting times etc. The format is indeed old-school, and you'd be unlikely to get this when booking online direct with EVA. That said, I received very similar GDS printouts in PDF form when booking via Thai Airways customer service in 2024, so this in itself is not a smoking gun.
The one thing I find surprising is the lack of an e-ticket number, which you'd usually expect to see on an issued airline ticket. It may be that the itinerary is from a tentative reservation that was cancelled before payment.
All that said, none of this proves that the person actually flew on these flights. Airlines are, correctly, very careful about who they disclose this kind of personal information to, short of a police warrant you'd have to get access to their frequent flyer records to confirm.

This is a valid EVA itinerary and in fact its the shortest and cheapest for these travel dates and most likely the first choice offered by a website. It's readily available on EVA's website.
The appearance of the booking varies all over the place depending on who the booking agent was. This, per se, is not a strong indicator of a fake booking.
You can probably check whether the booking is real by using the booking reference and the name of the traveler and putting in here: https://booking.evaair.com/flyeva/EVA/B2C/modifyflight.aspx Most airlines are surprisingly open with sharing your flight info with everyone who has your name and number (booking number, that is).


I used the booking reference number and passenger name with the link you provided.  It says it didn't have any record of the booking.

@Mike The booking is for flights over a year ago, it's probably normal the info is no longer available. I wonder what relevant use case may require you to know whether that itinerary from over a year ago is valid or not?

This individual extorted, manipulated and lied in a dizzying tangled web and I'm simply exploring all of the different possibilities.  This is just one of dozens of things I'm trying to clarify, simply to find out whats true and whats not.

@Mike Sorry to hear that, maybe safer and less distressing in the long run to assume it was all false, put it out of your mind and move on with your life.

Mike, if you send money or are still in contact with this person, report it to the police. Your local police station should be able to guide you to the best way to do that.
